# Remove focus from first invalid input in angularjs form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I having html form with angular-js and there is need to remove focus on required fields which are failed on submission. 
Actually I am showing all error messages in Pop-Up box. So there is no need to focus on failed controls.

Please help me for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I was using type="submit" for input @time of submitting form and Now by using type="button", resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on way you are starting you validation.

Assume you are doing this by **clicking** on some btn. 
If so, you should create [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which will subscribe to the click event 
and [do focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) to the document or other element you choose for this. 

Don't forget to unsubscribe your listner from the element on $destroy event with [.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

If you are using another way for starting validation you should subscribe to it and do the same.

Hope this was helpful.